# Characteristic subgroups of a direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product, characteristic-subgroups

Let $G=H\times K$ and $H\times 1$ be a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

Then can we conclude that $1\times K$ is also a characteristic subgroup of $G$?

---

My motivation is the case where orders of $H$ and $K$ are relatively prime. In that case, both must be characteristic subgroups of $G$. So I wonder: if one of the components is characteristic in $G$ then is the other, too?

Comment: strictly speaking that $=$ should be $\cong$

Comment: @janmarqz: I mean exactly the group $H\times K$ by saying $G$, why should I use $\cong$ ?

Comment: how is $H<H\times K$?

Comment: @janmarqz: ok, I edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no.

For example in $C_2 \times S_n$ ($n \geq 3$) the $C_2$ factor is characteristic because it is the center, but the $S_n$ factor is not characteristic: consider the automorphism $(x, \sigma) \mapsto (x \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma), \sigma)$.

With GAP you can find plenty of more examples.